# Teradata identity column and "Duplicate unique prime key error in dbname.tablename"

Tags: unique, identity, teradata

I created a table using the below definition for a Teradata identity column:

```
      ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 0 
            MAXVALUE 100000000 
            NO CYCLE),
----
      UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( ID )
```

For several months, the ID column has been working properly, automatically generating a unique value for the column.  Over the past month, however, ELMAH has been *intermittently* reporting the following exception from our .NET 4.0 ASP.NET app:

`Teradata.Client.Provider.TdException: [Teradata Database] [2801] Duplicate unique prime key error in DATABASENAME.TABLENAME.`

I was able to replicate it by opening SQL Assistant and inserting a bunch of records into the table with raw SQL.  As expected, most of the time it would insert successfully, but other times it would throw the above exception.

It appears that this error is occuring because Teradata is trying to generate a value for this column that it has previously generated.

Does anyone have any idea how to get to the bottom of what's happening?  At the very least, I'd like some way to debug the issue a bit deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the definition of your identity column to `GENERATED ALWAYS` to prevent the application or ETL process from supplying a value that could have been used. In fact, it is recommended by Teradata that if you are using your `IDENTITY` column as part of a UPI that it should be defined as `GENERATED ALWAYS ... NO CYCLE`

**EDIT:**

If your business requirements are such that you must be able to provide a value I would also consider using a domain that is outside the range of values you have set aside for the `IDENTITY` column. You can use a negative domain or a range that is an order of magnitude beyond that of the IDENTITY column. Personal preference would be to use a negative domain.

Comment: Doesn't `generated always` prevent you from inserting your own value into the identity column?  For reasons that I won't explain for the sake of keeping this simple, I require the ability to specify my own value for this field when inserting a new record, thus overriding Teradata's behavior of assigning a value itself.  When I want the database to generate it for me, I just don't include the field name in the insert statement.

Comment: When you encountered this error were you providing values in your raw SQL for the UPI or were you relying on Teradata to generate the identity values for you?

Comment: In this instance, I was relying on Teradata to generate the values.  This means I would use `insert into mydb.employee (name, email) values ('bob', 'bob@blob.com')` as opposed to `insert into mydb.employee (id, name, email) values (100, 'bob', 'bob@blob.com')`.  This has all been working since probably around February of this year.  Now we're starting to get this in our dev environment.  I am wanting to fix it before it starts happening in production because that would be bad.  When you say negative domain, do you mean use negative numbers for the primary key?  So someone's ID could be -100?

Comment: The ID column being populated by the IDENTITY column is a surrogate key that is being used as the primary index. A negative domain would ensure that values provided by a human never interfere with the domain you have allocated for Teradata to use in generating the IDENTITY value. The primary key is a logical construct that enforces uniqueness of an Employee. The primary index (unique or not) in Teradata is a physical construct that determines data distribution across the AMPS.

Comment: Can you create a copy of this table with the IDENTITY column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS ... NO CYCLE and try to reproduce the problem in development?

Comment: I could, but I think it's time to cut my losses on this and try a new method.  Being that it has been working fine for almost six months, there's no telling how many times I would have to insert records before I could reproduce it, and not reproducing it after inserting 1,000 records still doesn't mean it wouldn't have happened if I let it insert just one more record.  I've opened a new question that maybe you could help with:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744846/teradata-how-can-i-lock-a-table-for-read-and-write-so-i-can-execute-sql-and-the

Comment: See my response on your new question. :)